Electric moped PWM MOSFETs failure
I am back with my PWM moped project. Here is a link to my previous question if you're interested:
Advice about power MOSFET layout and heat management
Here is a quick summary of my circuit along with a schematic:


The MOSFETs are CSD19506KCS - I've used two in parallel
The MOSFETs are driven by one TC4427A - the driver is supplied by a separate 12V battery and fed a PWM signal at about 2kHz from a 555
The motor is an LEM-130 - a brushed DC motor with a peak current of ~100A
The motor is supplied with two lead-acid car batteries in series for a total of 24V supply
The diode is a VS-100BGQ10 100A Schottky diode
The capacitor is a PEH532RBI4100M2 1000uF electrolytic

The circuit in the dotted lines is on one board and as compact as I could manage.
Here are pictures:

What it looked like with the capacitor glued on the board:

The MOSFETs are on the other side of the board from the driving circuit, with a CPU heatsink mounted on them. Both drains and sources are connected to two separate copper bars that connect to the rest of the power circuit. The MOSFETs and the drain copper bar are screwed to the heatsink with some thermal paste between the bar and the heatsink.
The motor and lead-acid batteries are connected using thick car battery copper wire.
I took my bike for a spin and rode it for about 5 seconds before the MOSFETs burned (see above.)
The bike is very heavy (+ me on top it could total to about 100+ kg) meaning the motor is heavily loaded when starting, which translates to roughly between 50 to 100 amperes (that is my guess) going through the circuit for several seconds.
The failures that happened in the circuit:

Both MOSFETs failed, one cracked open around its source pin and the other got its source pin melted.
The capacitor fell from the board (its body was glued to the board using hot glue) and its positive lead came undone from its crimp terminal (I must have done a poor job at crimping it in the first place.) The capacitor was hot, not burning hot but apparently hot enough to soften hot glue.
The TLC555 is dead and the driver seems to be dead as well.

I have two hypothesis to why these failures happened:

The capacitor disconnected due to poor crimping or melting of the positive lead which in turn caused the MOSFETs to not be protected from ripples anymore. The MOSFETs in turn failed short from drain to source due to some ripple/spike, causing them to burn due to excessive current running through them.
MOSFETs were undersized and simply couldn't handle the current necessary for the motor to start, causing them to burn from overcurrent and therefore very fast overheating.

What I found strange is that the heatsink wasn't hot at all, warm at best.
My interpretation of all this is that two MOSFETs in parallel was not enough to carry this much current and I need to add capacitors in parallel to the main 1000uF one to help with ripple management. The 1000uF capacitor is clearly having too much current flowing through it (at least that's my intuition.)

I'm thinking of adding an additional driver and two more MOSFETs in parallel, for a total of 4 (I was even thinking 6 in parallel.) Do you think this would be a reasonable solution to the current carrying problem?
How can I improve the ripple management? Should I add a bunch of ceramic capacitors of lesser capacitance in parallel of the main one? Should I add one or two more large capacitors like the main in parallel to it so that they can accept more ripple current?
How do you think the driving circuit was destroyed? Is it possible for it to be destroyed from a surge going through ground or the gate pins?

Please tell me if my interpretations of these failures are correct and don't hesitate to correct me in any way and give me soldering/circuit building tips, as I'm learning electronics and wish to perfect my skills.
EDIT :
Here is closeup of both sides of the circuit :

The drive circuit is very straightforward : PWM output from the 555 circuit goes directly through the green wires to the inputs of the driver. The gate pins of the MOSFETs are bent, go through holes in the board and are soldered directly to the outputs of the driver on the other side, as can be seen on the pictures. There is no gate resistor for either MOSFET as the pins connect directly to the driver outputs. Driver connects directly to ground through the small black wire underneath the green ones.
The source copper bar to which the source pins are soldered is directly screwed to the board, connecting together the bar and the ground planes from both sides of the board.
Underneath the heatsink is the drain copper bar to which the MOSFETs connect through their backsides (drain pins have been cut).
Regarding the capacitor coming loose, I don't know which happened first as when I looked at the circuit right after the MOSFETs blowing up I noticed the capacitor hanging only by its negative wire, the positive terminal already undone. I think the crimping was bad, I should have added solder as well after crimping.

Use MOSFET driver IC instead, but built-in overcurrent, overtemperature etc. Plain "dumb" MOSFETs tend to pop like popcorns when used in applications like this, even if correctly dimensioned for the currents.

See this post for correctly paralleling MOSFETs: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/722483/166672

Please show the control/driver schematic -- of particular interest, the gate drive and resistors, and how they are wired in common to the source connection (I can't see these under the heatsink pictured).

Do you know if the capacitor came loose first, or later (perhaps while taking things back apart)? Perhaps you ran over a bump and bad things happened?

@TimWilliams - I've edited my question to give a more detailed view of the drive circuit. Is the layout of the parts and the construction correct ? Would you add gate resistors ?

If heat is actually the problem, you should change the "PCB substrate" with a pure copper sheet.
This allows the thermal resistance to be reduced not just a little, but by several orders of magnitude (easily x1.000 - x10.000)!
It looks like a lot of copper, but thermal conductivity is not really the advantage Manhattan style designs...

I think I can see enough from the photos to figure out what's happened.  Mind, leaving it to others to puzzle things out is risky -- or likely to generate dubious answers or low activity -- clarity and precision is everything in technical fields like this!
Start by evaluating switching performance.
At the gate drive, it appears you have zero resistance:

In red, I've marked the apparent connections and IC pin numbers.  VDD comes in on the red wire, pin 3 goes to GND.  Construction is Manhattan-style, with a sliced-up square of copper clad to furnish connection pads.  This is generally effective construction -- the main complaints here are that pins 3 and 6 could be shorter (to GND), and in particular pin 6 should have an adjacent 1µF ceramic capacitor to keep inductance low.
Additional bypasses are not required; the 555 hardly draws any current (peak or continuous).  Replacing the electrolytic is not actually desirable; it's preferable to have some to dampen the ceramic's low ESR, actually.  Though I would increase it to 10µF.
On the backside, it appears to be:

Amidst the magic smoke, I can't quite make out the body outlines, but they seem to be somewhere around here. In particular, the bodies are face-down, given the connections.  Possibly the drain tabs are soldered or bolted to the bus bar underneath the heatsink, I can't tell.
The transistors are probably not the hottest components anyway, but the diode is dropping a solid, almost a volt, under most load conditions.  It's not heatsunk either, though that might still take longer than 5s to get to dangerous temperatures.
In any case, it seems the gate terminals arch through holes in the board, connecting directly to the driver.  Mechanically expedient, and seems to confirm RG = 0.
Let's take a look at the switching loop:

From the description, it sounds like the main power connections are as here (yellow).  This gives a switching loop as in green, between cap, diode and switch.  Which I'm guessing, has a perimeter of a couple 10cm or so, or around 100nH ballpark.
The transistor rating is 80V, diode 100V, and supply 24V, so for switching 100A, we must have the transient overvoltage less than 56V.  Or \$\Delta t \ge \frac{L \, \Delta I }{V}\$ = 180ns or so.
That's not painfully slow, actually, despite the loose switching loop.
The loop could be greatly improved by simply tacking on some smaller (say 1000µF 50V) electrolytics (much smaller, more compact -- and can fit more of them!) between bus bars, bringing the battery terminal down alongside GND to make a sandwich against the PCB / ground plane (insulated, obviously :) ).  And then the diode can be right in there beside the transistors (preferably inbetween them, say?), and then the loop inductance will be down around 20nH, a substantial improvement.
But as-is, we should want switching much slower still, say 300-500ns, to avoid excessive peak voltage, while affording some more peak current capacity (since there's no current control in the circuit, and you're basically limiting by motor plugging current and battery resistance here(!)).
Why not switch faster?  Excess voltage generated in the loop, destroys the MOSFETs:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

This isn't even a great simulation (a finer timestep is needed), and even with a generous common-source inductance of 20nH (it's probably more like 5-10 in circuit) the peak is over 65V.
Note that this waveform would be measured common to the electrolytic's negative terminal, something of an odd place to probe.  Looking at it from the PCB ground instead, it will have a significant fraction of those spikes superimposed on it.  The wiring inductance is distributed through the loop, and what signal is measured, depends on the path and location it's measured at.

How do we calculate transition time for the NexFET(s) used here?
Well now, that's a good question.  You see, NexFETs are a modern lineage of low-voltage MOSFETs, having exceptionally low feedback capacitance (Crss), meaning the drain transition speed can be wildly faster than the gate's -- it's hardly limited by Miller effect, if at all.  Roughly speaking, we need QG(tot) / QGD times longer gate transition, or 120nC/20nC = 6x; for an output transition rate of 500ns, we need more like 3µs at the gate!  For an average gate capacitance around 12nF, that suggests a resistance of a whopping 250Ω!
In contrast, the 1.5A driver rough-dogging the gates can drive a transition in about 120nC/1.5A = 80ns give or take, but almost certainly less than 120ns -- guaranteeing excess drain peak voltage, avalanche, and eventual failure.
This might actually be a good application to recommend adding back in Miller capacitance; an external say 470pF+10Ω from D to G should have a significant impact on switching speed, bringing the gate and drain transition times closer together -- the corresponding increase in drive requirement is fine, you have tons to spare with that dual driver, but taming the transistors, and the large switching loop, is paramount.
Note that each transistor needs its own gate resistor, as in general they won't switch at the same time, and you don't want one hogging all the current (and with a 400A pulsed rating, it's more than capable of doing so!); independent gate resistors allow them to synchronize a bit more (particularly if Miller compensation is added -- again, per transistor).
As for failure mode, or sequence of events:
It seems most likely that avalanche and overheating destroyed the transistor(s).  One will tend to draw more current, as in general their avalanche breakdown voltages don't match, and the lower voltage hogs more current (not all, they will share to some extent, and voltage rises with temperature so it's not a runaway situation like parallel diodes).  This causes it to heat up, but it also causes degradation of the part itself: except for the oldest families (you often see this rating on HEXFETs), nothing today is rated for repetitive avalanche, and there is a wear mechanism that occurs.
It's also possible that the capacitor came loose first, exposing the transistors to wildly excessive peak voltages.  Avalanche ensues, greatly increasing power dissipation, and overheating and destruction soon follows.  (It may also be that excess avalanche current was delivered, causing prompt failure.)  Lesson learned: don't use hot glue to secure components, especially important ones like this.
Don't cheap out on crimps either.  If you absolutely must do it "wrong", do it wrong but better: squash the barrel to hold the wire in place, then fill it with solder (make sure a good fillet is made).  You aren't supposed to solder and crimp a terminal, but clearly it's not been crimped (wire pinched precisely by compression of the barrel around it) and a gas-tight joint has not been formed, so the associated dangers of soldering (mainly fatigue and cold-flow) don't apply here.  Think of it as a solder-pot joint, where the wire merely resides in a metal ring filled with solder (that the ring has been squashed, or is fairly tight-fitting otherwise, isn't really very important here; clearance is clearance, and clearance means a good solder joint).
It could even be that lead failure occurred, first, or during breakdown caused by the above failure.  TO-220s are only rated for 100A on a good day (they're really stretching things by putting 150A in the datasheet!!), and I wouldn't go above 50A myself.  Mechanical fatigue could also be a cause, I don't know.
You should use TO-247s here (two would be enough), or many more transistors in parallel (at least four).  Depending on how much current your battery and motor are capable of, short-circuit, it might be that the transistor leads simply fused (and perhaps the ensuing change of current and voltage blew up the rest of the circuit), or that they overheated first (or died of avalanche) and then the ensuing short-circuit current into the motor blew out the leads (and everything else).
Some manner of semiconductor breakdown is likely, given the driver damage.  Typically a transistor fails as a three-way short, and, obviously with the source pin lifted by melting, full battery/motor voltage is applied to the remaining pins -- backflowing 24V (or extra peak) into the driver and oscillator will quickly cause their destruction, being 18V rated parts.  Note that this current is not limited by any gate resistor (aha!), nor is the peak voltage particularly well limited by supply impedance: that measly 1µF electrolytic has an ESR of a couple ohms probably, not really enough for the driver in the first place (along with the lead length, this is where the recommended ceramic capacitor (above) comes from), but also not going to limit peak voltages under transient/fault conditions such as this.

Thank you very much for your in-depth and detailed answer ; the mosfets are as you drew, only flipped upside-down, so that the drain bus bar is sandwiched between the heatsink and the metallic drain backside of the mosfets. My idea was that the mosfets would evacuate their heat through the drain backside into the bus bar and then into the heatsink ; the entire assembly being held tight together by screws going through everything. I'm not using the plastic case to evacuate heat but the drain metal side

Regarding the Manhattan construction, I now understand that the purpose of it is to be able to place capacitors to ground next to Vdd pads. Would you recommend adding ceramic capacitors in parallel of electrolytics systematically ?

Could you please explain again why you want to increase the drain transition time ? When you talk about transition time, do you mean the time it takes for the gate to go from discharged to saturation, or the drain to go from cutoff to saturation ? Won't a longer transition time cause more heat dissipation in the mosfets as they spend more time in linear region ? I kind of get that sharper switching causes more voltage transients but if we want to minimize heat we need to switch as quickly as possible, right ?

My mosfet knowledge is clearly not on point, I need to go back to the theory to be able to fully understand everything you told me. I might end up using these https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfp2907pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535628b2d51fe8 as they are TO-247, only they have larger gate charge. Anyway, thank you for your time and all the precious information you have provided

You want to switch only as fast as the circuit can handle. Faster, and it destroys itself.  A tighter layout can switch faster, or use lower voltage devices (40V rating would be perfectly viable, perhaps even SMTs, but you'll need a more careful arrangement of bus bars to enable that). Considering the 1.5A gate drivers can transition in about 100ns, drain transition can be about 20ns, and peak voltage due to layout will be very high indeed.  It may very well have died of avalanche, and the capacitor falling out was coincidence. Both are identified problems.

Unless you're completely out of them, I don't mind the NexFETs -- just use more in parallel. Should be plenty of room on that heatsink for four? Ancient HEXFETs are quite poorer performing as you've observed (comparable or worse ratings, Qg(tot) many times higher), which does make them switch slower (an advantage if the layout isn't improved), and they are also repetitive avalanche rated (a tradeoff whether to bear avalanche directly, or switch slower to avoid generating excess peak voltage).

Ok, it is much clearer to me now, especially the importance of getting the switching loop as tight as possible. It's about finding the best tradeoff between heat generation (slower switching) and overvoltage transients (faster switching). I've been reading these kind of application notes https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Designing_with_power_MOSFETs-ApplicationNotes-v01_02-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7ddc01d7017e6c619a490f47 and they are technical enough to wrap my head around concepts better.

Thank you very much for the simulation. I get that in reality wiring inductance is not lumped but uniformly "spread" across the length of wiring, so the signal measured evolves uniformly as well. Even then, if I can manage to sandwich the bus bars as close together as possible using insulating sheets, the magnetic fields should cancel each other and the inductance should decrease, right ? Also, what do you think about a snubber across the mosfet from drain to source ? My guess is that it would help dampen the spike but slow down the switching.

Yes, that would be an improved arrangement. Snubbing reduces the switching loop around the transistor(s), permitting them to switch faster -- but you still have to absorb the energy of the wider loop, so end up costing about as much (or more, more or less because you've attached more elements now) power as in the original case. Keep in mind, energy stored is 0.5 L I^2, repeating at Fsw. Because Fsw is so low, the average dissipation isn't a big deal.

Everything is underrated including the "standard ESR" Cap. 150 mΩ * 1 mF = 150 µs = Tau.
You need a Tau near 1 µs (= low ESR type)
Also with a much larger C which means ESR < 10 mΩ. With a ripple current rating of 25-50 A. Your cap is only rated for 1.9 Arms. The PEH200MV6100M is rated for 40 Arms and is 100 mF, 63 V, 5 mΩ. (Tau=0.5)
When you start a DC motor with full power it will initially draw > 10x the rated current and power. So limiting the acceleration is critical.
Much more physics calculations and thermodynamic energy transfer must be computed with soft-start to handle accelerating this 100 kg mass.
The ultra-low RdsOn, and low ESR will cause high Q RLC ringing unless properly damped with RCD snubbers.
The resistance and reactance of every component in the power loop must be specified at switching pulse widths. That is ESR of cap, RdsOn at max T, DCR of motor, Rs of diode, and ESR of battery with 50% SOA margins on max current-seconds.
You will likely need SiC FETs or IGBT's rated for >= twice the current you plan to use. ( but likely over your budget)
Possible caps:
https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/B300/KEM_PEH200_DB-EN.pdf
The important rating is 50% more than Vbat min and Ripple current rating 50% more than expected. e.g. 50A rms  15mF 40V
Whenever you use 100% of max rating assume its temperature is at max and has required heatsink.
<= Verify if Motor DCR is 41 m&ohm  =>
Consider these FETs on a heatsink like a GPU with a turbine fan.
A bunch of these (maybe ) https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRFP4368PBF/1982960  also multiple Diodes and very short source paths to Gnd to battery to minimize ESL.
When duplicating FETs in parallel due to junction capacitances and dV/dt duplicate Rg, FET and Diode at I/O nodes. This will reduce flyback resonance effects if Vt's are not matched (+/- 50 % tolerance)

You can get 10pc's for ~ $20 HY5208W are better FETs.
https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_1811151155_HUAYI-HY5208W_C330384.pdf

This fan and Heatsink is too small for FETs and Diodes but along the idea that I had in mind, with a copper heatpipe and turbine fan for > 3m/s velocity otherwise far better than your (FET soldering iron). Then a thermal fan speed control is desirable.

You can use a few of the Infineon FETs you have IRFP2907 but at reduced Vds of 60V if you drive the gates with 3 to 10 ohms each and mount them on a proper heatsink.  I suggest a complementary emitter follower or equiv. IC. These can be PN2222A's for NPN for better current gain or equiv.  and similar for PNP.
There is no "trick"  every part change affects most other parts. The most critical is the total ESR of the Battery, Motor, FETs is an unknown and you are essentially shorting out the battery for xx microseconds starting up and ramping up PWM d.f. slowly. The peak powers are in kW shared by the FETs.


Could you explain where the tau comes from? -- what circuit parameters motivate that particular time scale, in particular how it relates (if at all) to switching frequency, peak current, device ratings, etc.? Regarding SiC or IGBT, could you explain how these high-voltage, faster-speed (in the case of SiC) devices would improve the design of a low-voltage motor controller being undertaken by a self-admitted newbie?

Tau and ripple current rating are inversely related.  I^2ESR caused the cap heat. For the FET CossRdson = Tau has the transition time Pd issue improved greatly by SiC and also for lower  for I^2 RdsOn

Are you referring to the same tau? A typical device in these ratings might have say 1nF Coss * 10mΩ Rds(on) = 10ps tau, but you suggest 1us, a difference of 10^5, please confirm?

10mΩ is too high for a 100A motor with a transition power just over 55 % of V*I rms= 1.5kW (triangle)  You are comparing a conductor (FET) with a thermal insulator (Cap) incorrectly.  Tau (C) correlates to low and std ESR and ripple current.  low ESR <10us typ. & Std > 100us typ.

@D.A.S. - Thank you for your reply ; why do you suggest a higher capacitance ? I understand the lower ESR and higher current rating for decreased heating and faster transition. For the snubber, I was thinking of adding one in parallel of the main capacitor consisting of lesser capacitances in series with resistors ; what values would you recommend ?

@D.A.S. - Ultimately I want the system to be able to start from static all the way to full speed without heating too much. Paralleling more of the mosfets I've used is not a good idea to you ? What part would you recommend ?

There is no single part solution.  IF your motor is capable of 100A @ 24V = 2.4kW (with a fan) it must have a small DCR to be efficient and you need series R of all other current paths to be cool, which isn't feasible. 2.4 W/ 2.4kW or a thousand times smaller ESR, RdsOn.  Even the motor will get hot with 83% eff. or 17% loss * 2400W = 408W in a tiny motor !!

if RdsOn is 0.5  moHm and motor is 17% loss at 24V/100A = 41 mOhms, that might work for efficiency ratio, but then switch capacitance goes up when RdsOn goes down.

A bunch of these maybe and also parallel the Diodes,  https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRFP4368PBF/1982960 with adequate forced heatsink

or the replacement p/n

I have a bunch of these already https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfp2907pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535628b2d51fe8 , would they do the trick ? I was told not to use them in a previous question because of their high gate charge, what do you think about that ?

Your motor is running at 24V. According to the MOSFET datasheet, at that voltage the safe operating current of a single CSD19506KCS is only 5A, which is not even enough to run your motor under no-load condition (6A per the motor datasheet). With any actual load, and especially in the initial motor stall state that occurs when first overcoming static friction, which can draw up to 100A, even two MOSFETs in parallel will quickly exceed their maximum SOA. (The situation will also be slightly worsened if the MOSFETs don't come from a matched pair, causing one of them to absorb a bit more current than the other and leading to a cascade failure in your setup.)
I think the solution is to find a much more capable MOSFET that can handle the combination of current and voltage you're throwing at it all day long.


The transistors are driven saturated (or, I certainly hope they are, but it's doubtful they would survive anywhere near 5s if that weren't the case); they never experience 24V across them while sinking any current.  The OA is on the left (black diagonal).

@TimWilliams During turn on, the mosfet traverses a VDS path from 24V down to 0V. This takes some time. A slow driver or high impedance gate connection will destroy the mosfet due to excursion beyond the SOA during this time. The mosfet survives only 11A when fully turned on anyway, and the 100A motor stall inrush will last much longer than the switching. So the mosfet will be outside the SOA as soon as it turns on!

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The big purple arrow is pointing to the DC curve -- surely this much time is not being taken.

Ah yeah, I can see the driver is directly wired to the transistors, so transition times will be well under the DC curve.

Thank you all for your replies ; I thought MOSFETs could be paralleled because of their negative temperature coefficient ? Why would they specify 150A maximum continuous current (from datasheet) if the mosfet can only handle 11A when Vds is zero (which is supposed to happen when the mosfet is in saturation) ?

No It is the PTC (not NTC) effect that increases resistance and current if too hot.  There are wirebond fuse limits (i^2t) and heat loss limits for current with Rja thermal resistance which are different.  NTC as in BJT's leads to thermal runaway.

Yes, positive coefficient for mosfets is what I meant to say. I once read in a book, as you said, that bjts cannot be paralleled because of their negative coefficient causing one component to take all the current. Thank you for your replies
